# Quickreport - how to print different pages?

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I need to print a report composed by multiple pages. 
I mean, for example, that if my report is composed by 4 pages in A4 format, and I have 10 records i need to  see: 
-record1page1 
-record1page2 
-record1page3
-record1page4 
-record2page1 
-record2page2
 and so on till 
-record10page4.

I tried with the QRCompositeReport, adding 4 QuickRep components  but when I print  I get all page 1 for the 10 records and then all page 2 for all 10 records and so on.
What is the solution?
Thank you

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with QR, but here's an idea: Create a group which starts a new page, and then add an artificial value to the reporting data, which will break on that group value exactly where you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i didn't understand your solution. Which group do I have to create? I am still trying and i am  able to print 2 pages, using a qrreport with a detailband and his childband, but if i try to put the other two pages that i need in other two childband, those are simply ignored on the final print.

Comment: Add a TQRGroup band to the QuickRep1 and set it's .Expression value to a value that allows for the grouping you want. Then set the QRGroup1.ForceNewPage to True, so that each group starts on a new page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not understand how to use the TQRGroup component. What do I have to set on Expression? Where do I have to design my 4 pages of the report?

Comment: It looks like you will need to read a tutorial document [here](http://ftp.qbss.com/qreport/files/level0/QR3TUT.PDF) and watch a tutorial video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVtRR_xkJFo) to get you started with the basic concepts and techniques of Quick Reports.

Comment: I read all but there is not the solution for. Maybe the problem is that i cannot explain my needs.

Comment: I try again: I have one table with N records(example: 5 records). I have to print each of this records on 4 different report pages (example: page A, page B, page C, page D). 
My target is to get a print file with, in sequence: the record 1 the page A, then page B, then page C, then page D;  and then record 2 page A, page B etc. So: 1A 1B 1C 1D 2A 2B 2C 2D 3A 3B 3C 3D 4A 4B 4C 4D 5A 5B 5C 5D.

Comment: The problems are these: if I use a qrCompositReport I'll get this: 1A 2A 3A 4A 5A 1B 2B 3B 4B 5B 3A 3B etc. So I have tried to use bands: I reached my target doing this: I put a DetailBand, then I checked HasChild. In the new Childband I checked againg HasChild and so on till I have 4 bands, and I set all childBands ForceNewPage property to True. 
Printing this I got almost what I need; 1A 2A 2B 2C 2D 3A 3B 3C 3D 4A 4B 4C 4D 5A 5B 5C 5D.

Comment: As you can see for the first record QuickRep prints only the first band, I don’t know if it is a bug or not. I fixed this setting KeepOnOnePage to true for the ChildBands, but only on the first record. The result is now ok. 
The only bad thing of all this is that Every time that I have to change a page of the report I have to put the other bands size to 0 and expand the band that I need, it is laborious but it works